# How do i use <tr> </tr> over <br> for images

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and trying new things out. Is it possible to store each of these repeating images in a `tr` and have 5 separate rows? I currently have a break tag every time the seat reaches 20(19) but i prefer to have it in a row tag. The reason I want it to be in a table is so I can display a number/text under each image so the user knows what the  number/text assigned to each image is. I would really appreciate someone's opinions.

My code is per below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var x= new Array(100);
var myseat="";
var test="";
var noseats=0;
var seatcounter=0;  

function seatgen()
{

   for(i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
      myseat+="<img src='seat_avail.png' onclick='mycheck(this,"+i+")'  width='45' height='70'>";          /*alt='seat"+i+"' id='mys"+i+"' onclick='mycheck("+i+")'*/

      if( (i+1) % 20 == 0 ){ myseat+="<br>" }

      x[i] = "available";
   }

   document.getElementById("seathere").innerHTML=myseat;
   noseats=prompt("How many seats would you like to book","10" );

}


function mycheck(k, p)
{
   if( x[p] != "available" ){
      alert("Not available");
   } else if( seatcounter == noseats ) {
      alert("Reacher max seats");
   } else {
      k.src='seat_select.png';
      x[p]="unavailable";
      seatcounter+=1;
   }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Is your seatgen function supposed to fill a table of images?

Comment: Hi Travis, yes that is basically what im trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Change to something like:

```
function seatgen()
{

 myseat = "<table><tr>"; // open table and first row

 for(i=0;i<100;i++)
 {
   myseat+="<td><img src='seat_avail.png' onclick='mycheck(this,"+i+")'  width='45' height='70'></td>";         

   if((i+1)%20==0){myseat+="</tr><tr>"} // close row, start new one
   x[i]="available";
 }

 myseat += "</tr></table>"; // close last row and table
```

This will generate rows with 20 images each, each in a table cell.

**Edit: working [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8ryLfu5g/1/)**

Comment: Hi Axel, i've change my script to the above but its currently not displaying anything at all,

Comment: You probably need to call the script on `dom ready`, not before, otherwise the target element isn't avaliable

Answer (score 0):

Each line need to be within   block.

```
myseat+="<table>";
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    myseat+="<img src='seat_avail.png' onclick='mycheck(this,"+i+")'  width='45' height='70'>";         

   if((i+1)%20==0){myseat="<tr><td>"+myseat+"</tr></td>"}
   x[i]="available";
}

myseat+="</table>";
```